# Redis LPOP wrong number of arguments in Python

Tags: python, redis

I have a simple Redis command that does the following:

```
redis_conn.lpop(queue_name, batch_size)
```

According to the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/LPOP) and their [Python SDK documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=lpop#redis.commands.CoreCommands.lpop), this should be a valid request. And, yet, I get the following error:

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'lpop' command

Maybe I'm being obtuse and making a noobie mistake because it's 2:00AM but, this should work. So why doesn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I was being obtuse. The documentation I linked states that the `count` argument is available from version 6.2. However, since I'm running Windows I don't get the newest version, ergo the failure.

Comment: I was about to comment asking what your versions of Redis, redis-py, and Python are. Glad that my thinking was going down the correct path. Generally when there's a weird mismatch from the documentation like this, it's from something being a different version than the documentation, in my experience.

Comment: @RandomDavis Agreed. I can't tell you how many times I've been bitten by my outdated version of Redis. The woes of a Windows scrub :(

Comment: You can always use [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) if you want to run Linux software via Windows. Should allow you to run the latest version of Redis. I used WSL to run the Linux version of Git on my Windows machine, and because it uses a Linux filesystem, it's able to do certain operations many many times faster. So it's not necessarily going to impact performance.

Comment: Only if you can enable Hypervisor, which I cannot as I'm running Windows Home